# using Intersection Observer to play/pause video in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intersection-observer

I got a child component called `Video` in my web app with a separate scrollbar enabled inside, where a list of video loads each taking the full height and width of the `Video` component. I'm using `Intersection Observer API` inside `useEffect()` to trigger a pause of the current playing video when the user scrolls down to the next video and the next video should start playing immediately. And this should continue throughout the component. I'm unable to achieve the functionality till now, and my current function starts playing the videos on the list all at once.

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./Video.css";
import VideoFooter from "./VideoFooter";
import VideoSidebar from "./VideoSidebar";

function Video({ url, likes, shares, messages, channel, description, song }) {

  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);
  const videoRef = useRef(null);
                                      //NEED HELP OVER HERE
    useEffect(() => {
    let video = document.querySelector("video");
    let observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      (entry) => {
        if (entry.intersectionRatio != 0.5 && !playing) {
          videoRef.current.pause();
          setPlaying(true);
        } else if (playing) {
          videoRef.current.play();
          setPlaying(false);
        }
      },
      { threshold: 1 }
    );
    observer.observe(video);
  }, [playing]);

  const handleVideoPress = () => {
    if (playing) {
      videoRef.current.pause();
      setPlaying(false);
    } else {
      videoRef.current.play();
      setPlaying(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="video">
      <video
        onClick={handleVideoPress}
        className="video__player"
        loop
        ref={videoRef}
        src={url}
      ></video>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Video;
```

Comment: You're calling `pause()` if it's _not playing_ and `play()` if it _is_?

Comment: if it's playing then `pause` or f it's pause then `play`

Comment: Before your edit it said exactly the opposite.

Comment: I realized it and changed..but it makes no difference..any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Is the `Video` component a single video and does it live inside some kind of a container component? I'm a little confused with the word "child component" in your question, is it the container or a single child inside a bigger container?

Comment: @dongnhan `Video` component is inside a bigger component called `home` component.. And `Video` component` contains multiple videos one after another getting called dynamically from the database and is passed as props from the bigger home component

Comment: @surjendu_dey But the `Video` component contains only 1 `<video>`, how could it contains "multiple videos"? Did you mean you have a separate video list where you will scroll to the next video in the list and then the `Video` component will display the selected-by-scroll video? Maybe you could provide the layout or the sketch of your UI so we could understand your question better

Comment: @dongnhan exactly you got me. There is a list of video coming from the database and loading into the `Video` component. I want to pause a playing video when the user scrolls down to the next video in the list and the next video then starts playing

Comment: Your `Video` component contains only 1 `<video>` tag so it could not load a list of videos. Not sure if this is the hierachy you have in mind: `<VideoContainer><Video /><Video /></VideoContainer>`

Comment: @dongnhan I'm getting all the videos in the parent component and mapping them and passing them as props to the `Video` component like this  <div className="app">
      <div className="app__videos">
        {videos.map((video) => (
          <Video
            key={video._id}
            url={video.url}
            channel={video.channel}
            description={video.description}
            song={video.song}
            likes={video.likes}
            messages={video.messages}
            shares={video.shares}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>

Comment: @dongnhan all the videos are loading correctly and with the `handleVideoPress` method  defined I can pause/play them with click..but I need to pause/play the videos on scroll..I hope you got me now

Answer (score 1):

```
let options = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: '0px',
    threshold: 0.8
};

let callback = (entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (entry.target.id == 'myvideo')
        {
            if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                entry.target.play();
            }
            else {
                entry.target.pause();
            }
        }

    });
}

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
const videos = document.querySelectorAll("video");

videos.forEach(vide => {
    observer.observe(vide);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.